# How to print a value inside a map returning from a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

Here is a TableCell which is inside array.map((row,index) =>{})

```
 <TableCell component="th" scope="row" padding="none">
      {row.createdAt}
 </TableCell>
```

I want to pass this {row.createdAt} as a parameter in a function and instead of printing {row.createdAt} inside this  I want to print the value returning from the function. Please tell me how to do that??

Comment: Can you provide your function too and what type of component are you using?

Comment: `{fn(row.createdAt)}` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function within the bracket which are inside your `TableCell` Component

```
<TableCell component="th" scope="row" padding="none">
   {yourFunction(row.createdAt)}
 </TableCell>
```

You call a function in JSX by calling it within `{}`

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, just call that `function` and pass the `row.createdAt`

```
 <TableCell component="th" scope="row" padding="none">
      {this.yourFunctioName(row.createdAt)} // if class based component
      // OR {yourFunctioName(row.createdAt)}   if function based component
 </TableCell>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function then call it then pass the row.createdAt as a parameter

```
       function getCreatedAt(createdAt) {
          // Do something
          // HERE
       
          return createdAt
       }

       <TableCell component="th" scope="row" padding="none">
            {getCreatedAt(row.createdAt)} 
       </TableCell>
```